# Using WinUI3 and XAML data binding, how do you get a field to update when the source contains an indexing operation and is a subfield?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, winui-3

I have a state class named PlayerState that contains many fields I want to bind via XAML, so I want a solution that scales well.

I have this code in a ViewModel that inherits from the BindableBase class provided by Microsoft so that binding gets triggered when SetProperty is called. I have verified that SetProperty is called with data that is correct.

```cs
private PlayerState _playerState;
public PlayerState PlayerState
{
    get { return _playerState; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _playerState, value); }
}

internal void OnStateChange(PlayerState playerState)
{
    PlayerState = playerState;
}
```

I have this binding that contains a context to the ViewModel described above, and have no clue how I am supposed to debug XAML. The error I get is that `'Active' property not found on 'App.Models.PlayerState'`. All the fields in PlayerState are public and readonly.

```xml
<Image
    x:Name="ActiveImage"
    Source="{Binding PlayerState.Active.ImageFileNames[ImageSize.SMALL], Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=/Assets/BlankCard2.png}"
    Margin="5"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="5" />
```

I set the context in the code behind file.

```cs
public PlayerPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = ViewModel;
}
```

But when the PlayerState's Active field is changed and PlayerState updated, the binding does not update the image. Why?
The path `Active.ImageFileNames[ImageSize.SMALL]` is correct, because it works when I bind them to a ListView.

I would use `bind`, but it does not support indexing, so what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `ImageSize` is an `enum`, something like this:

```cs
public enum ImageSize
{
    SMALL,
    MEDIUM,
    LARGE,
}
```

But IIRC, bindings won't work with `Dictionary` with `enum` as its key, in this case, `Dictionary<ImageSize, string>`.

So, one workaround should be using `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Another workaround might be creating a value converter:

```cs
public class TestConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is IDictionary<ImageSize, string> dictionary &&
            parameter is string parameterString &&
            Enum.TryParse(parameterString, out ImageSize imageSize) is true)
        {
            if (dictionary.TryGetValue(imageSize, out var fileName))
            {
                return fileName;
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException($"Failed to convert to file name. [value: {value} / parameter: {parameter}]");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```xml
<Image Source="{Binding PlayerState.Active.ImageFileNames, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}, ConverterParameter='SMALL'}" />
```

**UPDATE**

This is the rest of my test code for this answer:

```cs
public class Active
{
    public Dictionary<ImageSize, string> ImageFileNames { get; } = new()
    {
        { ImageSize.SMALL, "Assets/Small.png" },
        { ImageSize.MEDIUM, "Assets/Medium.png" },
        { ImageSize.LARGE, "Assets/Large.png" },
    };
}

public partial class PlayerState : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Active? active;
}

public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private PlayerState playerState = new();

    [RelayCommand]
    private void Test()
    {
        PlayerState.Active = new Active();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

I'm using the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) NuGet package for the MVVM pattern and I recommend you give it a try. It's just amazing.

Comment: This makes sense, but 'Active' is the variable not found.

Comment: `Active` is just a property in `PlayerState`, right? I posted the rest of my test code for this answer.

Comment: [ObservableProperty] is definitely more scalable than defining setters and getters for everything, but is there no way to observe just one Object (PlayerState in this case) and then when it changes, access all it's non-observable fields (Active, etc in this case), and then update one View per non-observable field via binding? It seems like it should be doable in my case since the PlayerState updates are the only updates needed (the sub fields changing are just a side effect of the PlayerState changing). I am thinking like how data templates work in ListViews.

Comment: I guess no. If you might be updating some properties in the deep level, then those needs to notify the UI to update them.

Comment: Seems counterintuitive that such an approach is not implementable in the framework without some boilerplate. Like a simple observer pattern between the ViewModel and the code behind has like one line per View update.

Comment: For example, without making Active an observable property, in a PlayerStateChanged callback I can add this single line.
```ActiveImage.Source = (new BitmapImage(new Uri(ViewModel.PlayerState.Active.ImageFileNames[ImageSize.SMALL])));```
The data binding boilerplate needed to change the ActiveImage when PlayerState changes seems unreasonable.